# regex string that doesn't include ending forward slash (/)

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics

I have category pages and product pages.

I'm trying to write a regex string that includes all the category pages but excludes all product pages.

The category pages all have the following URL structure:

www.site.com/products/category_name   (note: no forward slash (/) at the end of the url)

The category names change depending on the category

The product pages all have the following URL structure:

www.site.com/products/category_name/product_name

Essentially I need a regex string that will capture everything that has www.site.com/product/category_name but doesn't contain an ending forward slash (/) or anything else after that either.

I've tried www.site.com/products/(.*)[^/] but that doesn't seem to work

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax should be

```
^www\.site\.com\/products\/(.*)[^\/]$
```

You need to escape dots and slashes.
Test : http://regex101.com/r/nK5mT3/1